# "Within" and "inside"

Tags: synonyms

I am used to thinking that "within" can be used interchangeably with "inside", and Merriam-Webster seems to [agree](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/within). Yet an editor of a scholarly publication marked the phrase "within the unit circle" as a usage error and noted that it should be corrected to "within the unit disk". Is he being too picky, or do the common phrases like "within reason" and "within the realm" hint that those two words are not the exact synonyms?

Comment: This isn't a question of "within" vs "inside" but rather one of "circle" vs "disk".  (And I frankly have never seen "unit disk" used before.)

Comment: In mathematics, the unit circle is just the boundary, whereas the unit disk is the boundary plus the interior. If you're not writing an article for a mathematics journal, I don't think you need to worry about this distinction.

Comment: @PeterShor - But how could a point be within the unit disk but not within the unit circle?

Comment: Yeah, I would say that "within the unit disk" is about the same as "inside or on the unit circle", if you defined "inside" as being at distance less than R from the center. If you are writing a math book, do not even try using common phrases as "within reason" as a guideline. This is why math books introduce carefully phrased definitions each time they talk about a new concept.

Comment: @PeterShor even if you are, "within the unit circle" seems to me to mean the exact same thing as "within the unit disk"; but "on the unit circle" and "on the unit disk" would be different.

Comment: If something is "within your grasp" it is not *yet* in your hands, and it certainly is not **inside** anything, now or then.

Comment: If something is within my grasp, it is inside my sphere of competence, is it not?

Comment: That is not "used interchangeably". They are not exact synonyms. It is not "inside your grasp".

Comment: The reviewer is apparently interpreting "within" to mean "a member of the set of points defined by". I don't know if that's a common distinction to make in mathematics, but if it is it's more of a question for the Mathematics Stackexchange than for English Language Stackexchange.

Answer (score -1):

A [disk](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/disk) is a flat circular object, while a [circle](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/circle) is an ellipse (in other words, a shape consisting of a circular line).

I suspect the editor regards the "unit disk" to be an object like a plate, rather than a simple shape, and that is the reason for the mark.

Comment: In mathematics, circle is the curve bounding a disk, the latter being a region of a plane.

Comment: Thank you. My math is not good.

Comment: Really we shouldn't be answering this here. It is, strictly speaking, a maths question.. You need to know about *intervals*. Read about the subject here. https://www.basic-mathematics.com/interval-notation.html. What is the subject of your paper? What discipline? The phrase sounds mathematical and yet you claim not to know about maths.

Comment: I don't claim that, you might be confusing me with@RobJarvis. The only math knowledge required has been supplied by @PeterShor